# Is there any way to replace all occurrences in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am learning Pandas Dataframe from [here.](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-tutorial-dataframe-python) I came across method `replace()`.
 Firstly a DataFrame df is defined which has following values:

```
     Student1 Student2  Student3
0          OK  Perfect  Acceptable
1       Awful    Awful     Perfect
2  Acceptable       OK        Poor
```

The tutorial asks to do the following :

```
df.replace(['Awful', 'Poor', 'OK', 'Acceptable', 'Perfect'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

After running that line of code, when I run `print(df)`, I still get the same result which is:

```
     Student1 Student2    Student3
0          OK  Perfect  Acceptable
1       Awful    Awful     Perfect
2  Acceptable       OK        Poor
```

When I searched for this method on stackoverflow, I came to know the correct line of code should be:

```
df['Student1']=df['Student1'].replace(['Awful', 'Poor', 'OK', 'Acceptable', 'Perfect'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

That updates only the column 'Student1'. So if I have, say 20 columns, then would I need to replace values in all 20 columns manually or is there a better way to replace all values at once?

Many Thanks.

**Edit:**

The solution mentioned in the comment @jezrael worked for me.

```
df.replace(['Awful', 'Poor', 'OK', 'Acceptable', 'Perfect'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],inplace=True)
```

Comment: You need assign back `df = df.replace(['Awful', 'Poor', 'OK', 'Acceptable', 'Perfect'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])` or `df.replace(['Awful', 'Poor', 'OK', 'Acceptable', 'Perfect'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], inplace=True)`

Comment: Untlis unless you are using `inplace` or assigning back to `df`, you are just changing a view of the dataframe

Comment: Thank you @jezrael . This worked for me.